# Splitting an array of info to send request and receive info properly React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to receive some info from an api using some ids and then saving the info to use later :

```
function useJobs () {
 const [tags, setTags] = React.useState({})
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchTags () {
      const tPromises = []
      for (const job of jobs) {
        console.log(job.tags)
        tPromises.push(fetchJSON(`/api/jobs/view-tag/${job.tags}`, { headers: headers })
          .then((tags) => {
            return { [job.id]: tags }
          }))
      }
      const dData = await Promise.all(tPromises)
      console.log(dData)
      setTags(prev => Object.assign({}, ...dData))
    }
    fetchTags()
  }, [jobs])

  return [jobs, locations, departments, tags]
}

function useJobs () {
const [jobs, locations, departments, tags] = useJobs()
......
{tags[job.id] && <Col key={tags[job.id].id}>Tags:{tags[job.id].name} </Col>}
```

but since `job.tags` is an array instead of a single string I cant send my request properly and I receive an error like this:

```
"GET /api/jobs/view-tag/10,12,13 HTTP/1.1" 404 7681
```

how can I split the `job.tags` array into its individual parts and send requests for each one of them and receive their info?

this is my job.tags arrays (I have 3 job objects and inside the arrays, there are tag ids that need to be sent for each job)

[image: this is the job.tags arrays and I have 3 job objects]

Comment: is `job.tags` an array of arrays?

Comment: for (const job of jobs) {
        console.log(job.tags)} the photo is the result of this @Yousaf

Comment: I have 3 jobs and each one has an array of tags with those ids inside @Yousaf

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each `job.tags` array and send the individual tag id in the request

You also don't need a `then` block inside the loop. `Promise.All` will resolve the promises after all promises have been pushed in the `tPromises` array

```
for (const job of jobs) {
   for (const tagId of job.tag) {

       tPromises.push(fetchJSON(`/api/jobs/view-tag/${tagId}`, {headers: headers})

   }
}

const dData = await Promise.all(tPromises)
console.log(dData)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for (const job of jobs) {
  for (const tag of job.tag) {
    console.log(tag)
    tPromises.push(fetchJSON(`/api/jobs/view-tag/${tag}`, { headers: headers })
      .then((tags) => {
        return { [job.id]: tags }
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: this one works, but it only returns one tag for each element, for example the tags in the array are css,js,html but this only prints css

Comment: Thats because it you are looping on a promise. It need to wait for response from every tag in every job in jobs

Comment: so what should I do if I want all of them to be displayed?